# Restrict file access to append only

Tags: linux, logging, log-files, file-permissions, xfs

I have a directory with log files and I'm putting
logs from script launched by users into them. Logging with syslog isn't
possible in this case.

I want the users to have only write permissions on log files.
The problem is, that write permissions must be restricted, so that 
they can **only append** to that files.
The underlying filesystem is XFS.

The following doesn't work:

```
# chattr +a test.log
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on test.log
```

Is there any other solution for this? Thank you for your hints.

***Update:***

The solution was:

```
# xfs_io
> open test.log
> chattr +a
> close
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for access control lists (ACLs). Search for this on google or SF.

Comment: Which version of Linux, kernel, distribution?

Comment: [Also posted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59864/restrict-file-access-to-append-only). [Don't do this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073)

Comment: Already asked for deletion there. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK chattr only works on ext* (ext{2,3,4}) and some other specific filesystems.
The xfs_io  man page does mention chattr though.

Comment: Actually, this worked out pretty well for me. Thank you. I had to open files through xfs_io and then used chattr command on them.